# Monotonic properties of an even function

Tags: real-analysis

I have an even function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow (0,+\infty)$ which is nondecreasing on $(0,+\infty)$ and for which there exist constants $0 < a \leq 2$, $b \geq 1$, and $c,d > 0$ such that
$$f(x) \geq \frac{1}{c} |x|^a I_{[-1,1]}(x) + \frac{1}{d}|x|^b I_{(-\infty,-1) \cup (1,+\infty)}(x)$$
($I_A$ denotes the indicator function of the set $A$). I'm trying to prove (or disprove with counter-example) that
$$0 < s \leq t \qquad \Longrightarrow \qquad \frac{f(s)}{s^b} \leq \frac{K f(t)}{t^b} \quad \mathrm{and} \quad \frac{s^a}{f(s)} \leq \frac{L t^a}{f(t)} $$
for some constants $K,L \geq 1$. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you rearrange, you will see that $K,L$ must also satisfy $(t/s)^{b-a}\le KL$ which is not possible for all $0<s\le t$.

Comment: Yes, it is.Take $b \leq a$.

Comment: No, it is not, take $b>a$.